# QueryParsingException failed to find geo_point field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting `QueryParsingException[[listings] failed to find geo_point field [location.coords]]; }]` and can't quite figure out why.

My Query

```
esClient.search({
    index: 'listings',
    body: {
        query: {
            filtered: {
                query: {
                    match_all: {}
                },
                filter: {
                    geo_distance: {
                        distance: '10km',
                        'location.coords': {
                            lat: parseFloat(query.point.lat),
                            lon: parseFloat(query.point.lon)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
});
```

My mapping (as you can see -yes, I did use geo_point type)

```
    body: {
        properties: {
            location: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    country: {
                        type: 'integer'
                    },
                    address: {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    suburb: {
                        type: 'string'
                    },
                    coords: {
                        type: 'geo_point',
                        precision: '3m'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

After looking up http://localhost:9200/listings/_mapping/my-mapping, I noticed the coords field have the lat, lon set to double - could this have something to do with it.

[image: json response]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turns out this was happening because of how I was defining the geo_point's precision (needs to be wrapped in fielddata property), oddly the JS api i'm using didn't throw any kind of error that I recall:

**Correct:**

```
coords: {
    type: 'geo_point',
    fielddata: {
        format: 'compressed',
        precision: '3m'
    }
}
```

**Incorrect:**

```
coords: {
        type: 'geo_point',
        precision: '3m'
    }
}
```

And voila...

[image: correct geopoint mapping]